# How to pass variables to admin-ajax.php in frontend of Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to update title of wordpress single post via admin-ajax.php. Everything works great when I am directly load http://mysite.url//wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=myactionname <sup>*</sup> but when I am trying to load it from frontend (single post), variables doesn't send correctly.

I am using Wordpress 5, Php 7.2, Nginx

Inside plugin:

```php
class AjaxUpdate {
    public $postid;
    public $new_title;


    public function __construct($postid, $new_title) {
        $this->postid = $postid;
        $this->new_title = $new_title;

        add_action('wp_ajax_myactionname', array( $this, 'do_updatepost'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myactionname', array( $this, 'do_updatepost'));

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'ajax_update_script'));
    }

    public function do_updatepost() {
        echo 'It Work Updatepost';

        $post_update = array(
            'ID'         => $this->postid,
            'post_title' => $this->new_title,
        );

        wp_update_post( $post_update, $wp_error );

        wp_die();
    }

    public function ajax_update_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script('ajaxpost', plugins_url('plugname/scripts/ajaxpost.js'), array('jquery'));
        wp_localize_script('ajaxpost', 'plugname', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('nonce-for-plugname'),

    ));
    }
}
```

inside template page of single post:

```php
$wpajaxupdate = new AjaxUpdate($postid, $new_title);
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var data = {
            action: 'myactionname',
            nonce: plugname.nonce,
        };
        jQuery.post(plugname.ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            alert('Worked: ' + response + JSON.stringify(data));
        });
});
```

If I am using this code inside plugin, set variables and load http://mysite.url//wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=myactionname everything works fine:

```php
$wpajaxupdate = new AjaxUpdate($postid, $new_title);
```

What I am doing wrong? What is the correct way to update wp post title via ajax?

Comment: Is `$postid` defined?

Comment: Yes, off course.